# Deploy to Vercel

Tags: javascript, next.js, jsx, vercel, app-router

I have a next.js projekt that works perfectly in the development mode. But wenn i want to deploy it to vercel i get the Errors: "Compiler server unexpectedly exited with code: null and signal: SIGKILL
" and "ReferenceError: location is not defined".
[Vercel Deploy Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTKJE.png)

```
"use client";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import React from "react";
import { auth } from "@/app/firebase/config";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import updateGitHubRepository from "@/app/api/updateRepo.mjs";
import updateImage from "./api/updateImage.mjs";
import { ToastContainer, toast, Bounce } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

export default function Home() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const [userSession, setUserSession] = useState(null);
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState("");
  const [role, setRole] = useState("");
  const [bioDE, setBioDE] = useState("");
  const [bioEN, setBioEN] = useState("");
  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState("");
  const [index, setIndex] = useState("");
  const [file, setFile] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter(); // Move the useRouter hook inside useEffect

  // Load user session from sessionStorage when component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    const sessionUser = sessionStorage.getItem("user");
    setUserSession(sessionUser);
  }, []);

  // Load GitHub file when user.displayName changes
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadGitHubFile = async () => {
      const fileUrl =
        "RAW MEMBER JSON FILE";
      try {
        const response = await fetch(fileUrl);
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(
            `Fehler beim Abrufen der Datei. Status: ${response.status}`
          );
        }
        const fileContent = await response.json();
        const members = fileContent.members;
        const index = members.findIndex((item) => item.id === user.index);
        const gitDisplayName = members[index].name;
        const gitRole = members[index].description;
        const gitBioDE = members[index].biographie.de;
        const gitBioEN = members[index].biographie.en;
        const gitImg = members[index].img;
        if (index !== -1) {
          setDisplayName(gitDisplayName || "");
          setRole(gitRole || "");
          setBioDE(gitBioDE || "");
          setBioEN(gitBioEN || "");
          setIndex(index || "");
          const inputPath = gitImg;
          const baseUrl = "https://www.DOMAIN.de/";

          // Verwenden Sie die URL-Klasse, um den vollständigen Pfad zu erstellen
          const fullPath = inputPath.replace("../", baseUrl);
          setAvatar(fullPath);
        }
        return { gitDisplayName, gitRole, gitBioDE, gitBioEN, gitImg, index };
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(
          "Fehler beim Laden der Datei von der URL:",
          error.message
        );
      }
    };
    if (user && user.displayName) {
      loadGitHubFile();
    }
  }, [user, router]); // Include router as a dependency
  const handleFileUpload = async (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    setAvatar(url);
    setFile(file);
    // Hier können Sie den Dateiupload-Code hinzufügen
  };
  const handleUploadtoGithub = async (index, fields, img) => {
    // Hier können Sie den Dateiupload-Code hinzufügen
    try {
      let link = avatar;
      if (file) {
        const uploadFile = file;
        const newFileNameWithoutExtension = "avatar"; 

        const extension = uploadFile.type.split("/")[1];
        const newFileName = `${newFileNameWithoutExtension}.${extension}`;

        const newFile = new File([uploadFile], newFileName, {
          type: uploadFile.type,
        });
        link = await updateImage(newFile);
        console.log(link);
      }
      const build = {
        id: index + 1,
        name: fields.name,
        description: fields.role,
        img: link || "",
        biographie: {
          de: fields.biographie.de,
          en: fields.biographie.en,
        },
      };

      await updateGitHubRepository(
        "USERNAME",
        "REPOSITORY",
        "BRANCH",
        "FILE",
        `members.${index}`,
        build,
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_API_KEY
      );
      toast.success("Erfolgreich Hochgeladen!");
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("Fehler beim Hochladen!");
      console.error("Fehler beim Laden der Datei von der URL:", error.message);
    }
  };
  return (
//HTML
  );
}
```

I tried serveral methods to solve the problem but nothing worked out.

Comment: I recommend you to try and separate parts of this page into their own components. That way your page component won't need the `use client` directive making it impossible to pre render your page. I suspect one or more of your imports are referencing `location` which is only available in the browser, in which case you might need to [dynamically import it](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#with-no-ssr). There is no easy way to do this when you have huge components like this that do lots of things.